# restore base64_encode image to a file system from database

Tags: php, mysql, image, filesystems

I'm saving some of my image in to mysql database using `base64_encode`.
now I want to restore them back to file system.

How can I do that?

Edit...!

Ok, I did not explain enough.

I use this code to encode my image and save them in to a blob table:

```
function base64_encode_image ($imagefile) {
$imgtype = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png');
$filename = file_exists($imagefile) ? htmlentities($imagefile) : die('Image file name does not exist');
$filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (in_array($filetype, $imgtype)){
    $imgbinary = fread(fopen($filename, "r"), filesize($filename));
} else {
    die ('Invalid image type, jpg, gif, and png is only allowed');
}
return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($imgbinary);
}
```

and use this code to show my image in browser:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) && !ctype_digit($_GET['id'])){
    die('Error');
} else {
    require_once( addslashes(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/config.php') );
    require_once( addslashes(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Functions.php'));
    $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query ("SELECT `id`,`cover_small` FROM `om_manga` WHERE `Active` = '1' AND `id` = '".sql_quote($_GET['id'])."'"));
    if (isset($row['id'])){
        header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        readfile($row['cover_small']);
    } else {
        die('Error');
    }
}
```

Now i want them back to a jpg file.

The size of all those image are less then 3kb.

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to be saving the data as base64? The encoded version will be 33% larger than the original, and you'll have the overhead of encoding/decoding. MySQL has a datatype made specifically for large binaries like images: the [`BLOB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).

Comment: @Ano - perhaps legacy code... Or a team leader wearing [blinkers](http://www.randydisert.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/horse_blinkers.jpg) :)

Comment: There's no evidence here that your image is stored base64 encoded since you're displaying it without decoding it. Are you sure the image is stored encoded? I think the new question is better answered with another question. Why should you extract the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode it the same way you encoded it...
[base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

You might want to store the file extension of the image when writing it to the database so that you can restore it accurately.  Just concatenate the new name with the existing extension.
What you should so is something similar to this :

```
// Retrieved values from database
$encodedImg = $sqlResult['encoded_img'];
$ext = $sqlResult['encoded_img_ext'];

// Concatenate new file name with existing extention
// NOTE : This parameter is a full path.  Make sure that the folder 
// you are writing the file to has the correct permissions allowing the
// script write access.
$newImagePath = "/some/path/on/the/servers/filesystem/";
$newImageName = $newImagePath."decoded_image.".$ext;

// Saving the decoded file with the new file name.
file_put_contents($newImageName, base64_decode($encodedImg));
```

Comment: +1 Good point about storing the file name (extension), which may not be common knowledge to all.

Comment: By using `pathinfo()` and storing the extension separately when **receiving** an upload, you can also validate certain types of files you want to allow (or exclude).  For example, when uploading an image file, one would "blacklist" extensions like `exe`, `bat`, `docx`, `pdf`, `mov`, etc... (**Non**-image file extensions)

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP's [base64_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function to convert the encoded data back to binary.

Since base64_decode returns a string, you can use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write the decoded contents to a file.

It makes me wonder why you're storing the image base64 encoded if you're not using it in that format. You could just as easily store the image in binary format in a binary blob column.

Base64 encoding adds a 33% character overhead (not bytes).

**Edit for revised question**

The answer to your second question is subjective without context. Without knowing the details of your system, I can't recommend whether you should extract the images.

Comment: If the characters are in the basic ASCII set (and the entire base64 alphabet is, that's one of the main reasons the encoding exists), UTF-8 won't have any overhead. It's pretty much the entire point of UTF-8: ASCII characters are stored in a single byte, everything else is encoded in two to four bytes.

Comment: @AnotherCode: You're mistaken, in a UTF-8 MySQL column, every characters take up 3 bytes.

Comment: This includes a TEXT column. This is why it's better to use BLOB for this type of stuff.

Comment: @Evert wow, that's pretty crazy, I never knew. Thanks for the comment, it's valuable knowledge.

Comment: @Evert, I think AnotherCode may be right for a UTF8 VARCHAR column, even though an index on the column will still allocate 3 bytes per character. I assume the image column isn't indexed, so it's not an issue.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Thanks for your answer. for my second question i think i use file system, because it can be cache